# Why JQuery global object is not accessible in javascript functon?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see snippet below:

```
var mySwiper = new $('.swiper-container').swiper({
    pagination: '.pagination',
    loop:true,
    grabCursor: true,
    paginationClickable: true
});
function moveslide(n) {
    alert(mySwiper)
}
```

In alert, it shows "undefined" I am not sure why? `mySwiper` is global and it is out of function in same block!

Please guide.

Comment: Show how and when you call `moveslide`?

Comment: I am using like that on a button click.<br> <input type="button" onclick="moveslide(2)">

Comment: I don't think `new ` is required there?

Comment: Thanks Arun, but removing new is not making any difference.

Comment: @curious What about full example or at least link to plugin?

Answer (score 2):

In comments, you've said that

- Removing `new` makes no difference, and
- You're calling `moveslide` from a button click

That tells us it's one of three things:

1. You're calling `moveslide` *before* the `var mySwiper = ...` line executes. Because `var` declarations happen before any step-by-step code in the context [they're "hoisted"]), the variable exists, but because the *assignment* on that line stays where it is, it's possible to call `moveslide` before `mySwiper` gets its value assigned to it.
2. The code assigning `mySwiper` a value may never get called at all. I'd put a breakpoint on it to see whether it does; perhaps an error (an exception, or a logic error) prevents the code from being reached in the step-by-step execution. That doesn't affect `moveslide` (function declarations are hoisted like `var` is), but would affect your code assigning to the variable.
3. (This is only possible *without* the `new` on the `var mySwiper = new ...` line) `.swiper()` returns `undefined`. That would be a **very** odd thing for a jQuery plugin to do, and if you have the problem even with `new`, then this isn't it, but I'll just include it for completeness.

   Side note: Why can't this happen with `new`? Because with `new`, the result of the expression will always be a non-null object reference, never a primitive: `new` creates an object and then calls the function you give it with that object available as `this`. If the function doesn't return anything, returns `null`, or returns any primitive value (including `undefined`), the result of the `new` expression is a reference to the object created by `new`; if the function returns a non-null object reference instead, the result is that object reference. So you can never get `undefined` back from a `new`.

---

Side note: From your question, you seem to be thinking it's a scope issue and puzzled why `mySwiper` wouldn't be in scope. That doesn't fit the symptom. If you're seeing `undefined` in the `alert`, then `mySwiper` **is** in scope; if it weren't in scope, you'd get a `ReferenceError` instead (because trying to read the value of a *variable* that doesn't exist is an error). I just mention this so that if you run into something similar later, you know it's not scope, but timing.

Comment: @curious: I don't know what you mean by "no luck." I guarantee you that what's happening is that either A) You're calling `moveslide` before the `var mySwiper = ...` is executed, or B) The `var mySwiper = ...` is never being executed. That's what fits the symptoms you've described.

Comment: @curious: Actually, now that you've removed the `new`, there's a third possibility: `.swiper()` is returning `undefined`. But it's not likely, that would be a very odd thing for a plugin to do.

Answer (score -1):

At the top of the page, inside `document.ready` function declare something like this:

```
var mySwiper; //making it global
```

and change the code as shown below (only remove `var`):

```
mySwiper = new $('.swiper-container').swiper({
    pagination: '.pagination',
    loop: true,
    grabCursor: true,
    paginationClickable: true
});

function moveslide(n) {
    alert(mySwiper)
}
```

Comment: If your idea is to wrap swiper creation with `document.ready`, then your text is incorrect (even after my edition). If so, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/nk9j8rL4/) is what you are talking about.

Comment: yes ur right  it is not working it seems like problem lies  in the this line->     new $('.swiper-container').swiper({